# Find minimum cost distance for given co-ordinates

Tags: java, algorithm

For given list of x and y co-ordinates, find the location of co-ordinate (cx, cy).
The distance to reach this co-ordinate is calculated using Manhattan distance, where the Manhattan distance between the points (x[i], y[i]) and (cx, cy) will be distance[i] = abs(x[i] – cx) + abs(y[i] – cy) .

The corresponding cost for that path (x[i], y[i]) to (cx, cy) is calculated as price[i] * distance[i]

The result I am looking for is the minimum cost to connect to the node (cx, cy) from all the co-ordinates provided in list x and y.
 `The size of list x and y is 1 to 10^3, size of price list is 1 to 50 and values in x and y is 1 to 10^4`

Example:

x = [1,3,2,4], y = [1,2,3,4], price=[1,3,2,4]

Result:

To get minimum cost we need to select (cx, cy) as (3,3).

Cost = 1 * [(3-1)+(3-1)] + 3 * [(3-3)+(3-2)] + 2 * [(3-2) + (3-3)] + 4*[(4-3)+(4-3)]
cost = 4 + 3 + 2 + 8 = 17

Return 17 as answer.

Here is my program using brute-force approach:

```
public int solve(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y, List<Integer> price){
    int minCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int n = x.size();
    // try all possible combnations of (cx, cy) from (0,0) to 10^4
    for(int i=1; i<10000; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<10000; j++) {
            // Get (cx, cy);
            int cx = i, cy = j;
            int currentCost = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                // Get (xi, yi)
                int xi = x.get(k), yi= y.get(k);
                int distance = Math.abs(xi - cx) + Math.abs(yi - cy);
                currentCost += price.get(k) * distance;
            }
            minCost = Math.min(minCost, currentCost);
        }
    }
    return minCost;
}
```

The logic looks fine, but here I am using 3 nested loops so time complexity is O(N^3).

Another idea I have is to find the median for given list of x and y co-ordinates as the position for (cx, cy), this needs only O(N) time.
But as the final cost also depends on price list, using median is not a correct approach to solve this problem.

What is the optimized approach to solve this in less time.

Comment: First hint: price(x) and price(y) are independent, so you do not need to check all possible (x,y) pairs, just maximize price(x) and price(y) independently.

Comment: Second hint: it seems that two points `(int x1, int y1, int p1)` and `(int x2, int y2, int p2)` could be replaced by single point `(double (x1*p1 + x2*p2)/(p1+p2), double (y1*p1 + y2*p2)/(p1+p2), int p1+p2)`, so you may find a "center of gravity" and after that check 4 nearest integer points, however I'm not sure this idea is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Manhattan distance metric, you can calculate the `cx` and `cy` coordinates independently.

The minimum total Manhattan distance to all points in the list could be found, as you said, by finding the median of all the x coordinates and the median of all the y coordinates -- easy.

Your points are weighted by price, however, so a simple median won't do.  The solution is easy, though -- just use a price-weighted median.  It's not hard to show that a point with price p has the same effect on the total cost as a point with price 1 that appears p times in the list.

For example, `y`s in order, multiplied by price:

1 * 1, 2 * 3, 3 * 2,  4 * 4

The prices add up to 1+3+2+4 = 10.  In the range from 0-10, give each `y`, in order, a length equal to its price:  [0,1) for y=1, [1,4) for y=2, [4,6) for y=3, and [6,10) for y=4.

10/2 is 5, which is in the range for y=3, so `cy = 3`.

For x, we get [0,1) for x=1, [1,3) for x=2, [3,6) for x=3, and [6,10) for x=4.  Again the half-way point is in the range for x=3, so `cx = 3`.

Comment: Can you please explain what is `use a price-weighted median` with an example. Also I am not able to understand this statement `It's not hard to show that a point with price p has the same effect on the total cost as a point with price 1 that appears p times in the list.`